# Show Pop Up on Non Blank Patch Value

Tags: powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have a Submit Button which patches data to a spreadsheet and want to have it set so a success message pops up when there are no errors and the patch is sent.

I have 3 objects with `visible = showPopup` with the screen set to `OnVisible = UpdateContext({showPopup:false})`

Currently have this for my `OnSelect` value for the Button

```
If(IsBlank(Column1.Selected.Value),Notify("Column1 can not be Left Blank",NotificationType.Error),
Set(varrecord,Patch{Column1:Column1.Selected.Value,Column2:Column2.Selected.Value,Column3:Column3.Selected.Value});
If(IsEmpty(varrecord),"",UpdateContext({showPopup:true}));
```

Column1 and Column2 are drop downs

However if the field is blank and I receive the Error Notification because column1 is blank
`UpdateContext({showPopup:true})` still runs even though varrecord1 is blank.

Column1 `items = ["","1","2"]` - Adding this in case the blank value which gives the error is still making the variable not empty. Not sure on that.

Thanks.

Let me know if an of this is unclear

Answer (score 0):

I have a few questions, what is "varrecord" initially set to?
I would prefer you use IsBlank() over IsEmpty() in such scenario's

I have provided a URL for better understanding

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/IsBlank-IsEmpty-or-quot-quot/td-p/180395

Hope I have answered your question

Regards
RT